# Laravel 5 after middleware not ran after Exception is raised

Tags: exception, laravel-5, middleware

When using an after middleware to transform data :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JsonMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param  Closure|callable $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        dd($response);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use App\Http\Middleware\JsonMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        JsonMiddleware::class,
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ];
}
```

**Exception\Handler**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected $dontReport = [
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
    ];

    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::report($e);
    }

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {    
        return response($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php

use App\Exceptions\FunException;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return response('This should be displayed as JSON payload - code 200');
});

Route::get('/fun', function () {
    throw new FunException('This is a fun exception, code 433');
});
```

The `dd($response)` is never ran when raising an exception, can I change that ?

Comment: Let us know if you found a solution :)

Comment: solution is dd = exit, when done